# Archive all chats in Google Hangouts

Tags: google-apps-script, chat, archive, google-hangouts

I'm looking to find / write a script to archive Google Chat messaged (hangouts). I thought that this would work, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Can anyone point out why its not working or what I've done wrong?

OR - If anyone else has a solution for what Im trying to do, that would be great too!

```
function ArchiveChats() {
var threads = GmailApp.getChatThreads(0, 100);
GmailApp.moveThreadsToInbox(threads);
GmailApp.moveThreadsToArchive(threads);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it gets the first 100 chat threads from anywhere in your mailbox rather than from your inbox.

Here's a function that will archive all chat threads that are not already archived:

```
function archiveAllChats() {
  var query = 'in:chats label:inbox';
  var MAX_THREADS = 500;

  var chatThreadsToArchive = GmailApp.search(query, 0, MAX_THREADS);                                         
  while (chatThreadsToArchive.length > 0) {
    Logger.log('Archiving %s chats', chatThreadsToArchive.length);
    GmailApp.moveThreadsToArchive(chatThreadsToArchive);
    chatThreadsToArchive = GmailApp.search(query, 0, MAX_THREADS);
  }
  Logger.log('All chats are archived');
}
```

Comment: This does remove them from my inbox, which is great. However, it doesn't remove them from the sidebar / google hangout applications. Which is what I was (ideally) trying to do. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, the hangouts api doesn't expose a way to programmatically archive a conversation. One option to put them out of sight there in the sidebar is to switch to the contacts list.

Comment: Ah that's a real shame. Thanks for your help anyway Peter! Much appreciated.